How to permanently save startx screen resolution
I'm using Ubuntu Server 24.04.1 on a Raspberry Pi 4B 8GB and 7" touchscreen with a USB interface. I have a software which is using a Python GUI. I set startx and I can run the program without an error.
I created a service like this:
[Unit]
Description=CPApp
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=root
Environment=DISPLAY=:0
Environment=XAUTHORITY=/home/enes/.Xauthority
ExecStartPre=/usr/local/bin/pigpiod
ExecStart=/usr/bin/startx /home/enes/cp/env/bin/python /home/enes/cp/main.py -- :0 vt7
WorkingDirectory=/home/enes
#Restart=always
#RestartSec=20
StandardOutput=null
StandardError=null

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

I tried lot of things about setting screen configuration to 1024x600, but it didn't work.
